# Comunication between Jquery and PHP failed

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am sorry again for my questions, but I can't get the solution for this Little Problem. Is the effects of to be a rookie :)

I have this JSON Format that represent a list of games with the rounds and the Player of each round. In the example is represented only 1 Game and 3 rounds:

```
{
 "1":
     {
      "4":
          {
           "Name":"Rocky",
           "Time":"00:00:23"
          },
      "11":
           {
            "Name":"Rudy",
            "Time":"00:00:36"
           },
      "25":
           {
            "Name":"Frank",
            "Time":"00:00:04"
           }
     }
}
```

And I hope it is a correct JSON Format :D

Now I send this to my PHP file and wait for the answer doing this:

```
var DataJSON = JSON.stringify(Data);//Data is the General array
$.ajax({
            data: { game: DataJSON},
            url:   'page.php',
            type:  'GET',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function (){
                alert('Information wird gespeichert');
                console.log(DataJSON);
            },
            success:  function (msg) {
                alert('Information wurde gespeichert');
                console.log("Succes" +msg); 
            },
            error: function(msg){
                alert('Server antwortet nicht. Fehler..');
                console.log("Error here" +msg); 
            }
        });
```

And the code of my PHP file Looks like this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if(isset($_GET['game'])) {

    $ga= json_decode($_GET["game"],true);
    foreach ( $ga as $ga){
        echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' .(json_encode($ga[0])). ')';
    }
}
else{
    echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' .(json_encode("not found")). ')';
}
```

But the answer of the console is:
"Error here [object Object]"

What I am doing wrong, PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: You're missing a `'` at `'page.php,`. `json_decode($_GET["game"],"true");` should be `json_decode($_GET["game"],true);`. For starters.

Comment: Hey Thx, yes was my mistake, I miss the ' in page

Comment: `foreach (i, $ga as $ga)` does it work? Never heard of passing 2 vars in `foreach` (being the first one `i` not even a var)

Comment: And I fixed also json_decode($_GET["game"],"true") now is json_decode($_GET["game"],true). But is not working :(

Comment: @AlanMachado correct this is not working I check it right now. You are right THX!

Comment: "11"{"Name" => "11":{"Name"

Comment: You're editing your question with the corrections but you're not telling if the error persists in your code or even if it changed for something else

Comment: @AlanMachado I fixed the Errors of editing, in my code is correct, I mean this were only editing mistakes. I made this mistake when I copy to the board. But anyway my Programm is not running :(

Comment: I do not see how `$_GET['callback']` is defined. It's not in your JSON, hence it will not get pushed to the the PHP.

Comment: @Twisty Thx very much for your answer and your help. Can you pls be so kind and tell me what $_G[] means? Till I know is $_GET[] or $_POST[] or $_REQUEST[] or something else. Are these obsolet? Grettings Zoe

Comment: I simply created a variable called `$_G` as an Array for the example. `$_GET` should be populated in a similar manner. Since I could not replicate your test environment, I had to make a test scenario that would mimic the data passed via `$_GET['game']`. Let me know if that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Tested using phpfiddle.org:

```
<?php

$_G = array(
    "game" => '{
"1":
     {
      "4":
          {
           "Name":"Rocky",
           "Time":"00:00:23"
          },
      "11":
           {
            "Name":"Rudy",
            "Time":"00:00:36"
           },
      "25":
           {
            "Name":"Frank",
            "Time":"00:00:04"
           }
     }
}',
    "callback" => "callback");

if(isset($_G['game'])) {

    $ga= json_decode($_G["game"],true);
    echo "<pre>";
    var_export($ga);
    echo "</pre>";
    foreach ( $ga as $ga){
        echo $_G['callback'] . '(' .(json_encode($ga)). ')';
    }
}
else{
    echo $_G['callback'] . '(' .(json_encode("not found")). ')';
}

?>
```

When you called `$ga[0]`, this was generating an error:

**E_NOTICE :** type 8 -- Undefined offset: 0 -- at line 33

Since there is no 0 index in your data, it failed. I removed the index in the code above and it executes properly. It's not clear what you want to do with the data, so if this does not work for you, comment, and explain your code further.

Here are the results I got:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    4 => 
    array (
      'Name' => 'Rocky',
      'Time' => '00:00:23',
    ),
    11 => 
    array (
      'Name' => 'Rudy',
      'Time' => '00:00:36',
    ),
    25 => 
    array (
      'Name' => 'Frank',
      'Time' => '00:00:04',
    ),
  ),
)

callback({"4":{"Name":"Rocky","Time":"00:00:23"},"11":{"Name":"Rudy","Time":"00:00:36"},"25":{"Name":"Frank","Time":"00:00:04"}})
```

Comment: Twisty thx very much I tested and is still not running. I just want to see or get per game which were the Players per round. I sent the complete Information to PHP and he shoul only return the names of the Players in each round. Can you pls help me? Thx!

Comment: You'll need to be more clear or post further details. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish at this time.